# How can i make navigation bar responsive on mobile devise

Tags: html, css, github

here is the link to my css file.[this is the image of my navivigation css script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAWtn.png)

Here is the html file screenshot of my navigation panel[This is the html screenshot of my navigation script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSU76.png)

Please i need help to make my navigation respomnsive on any mobile device as it does not work at all currently.

Comment: Could you put that in a snippet so that I can see what it does?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code as text (not images) and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add these links under the title in head

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

[follow this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH3WP.png)

Comment: can you please attach some screen shots of the web page and send me your html page code